# How to setup VPS server with node.js and specify the PORT?

Tags: node.js, http, server, port, vps

I have server on PORT 22, I connect  to this server on PuTTY correctly by this port. But when I start the server using `http-server` command in PuTTY and type the IP in browser, I just get Index of/ showing folder structure.

In my simple app.js I have got

```
app.get("/", function(req,res){res.send("test")});
```

It doesn't work anyway. Does someone know what am I suposed to do?

Comment: If you are seeing a folder structure then you have another web server running. What port is your node app running on? The `app.get()` parts are not important, show us your `app.listen`

Comment: I have got “app.listen(22) “ in app.js. I tried “ process.env.port “ but it makes an error.

Comment: I thought you said you're using port 22 for ssh access (PuTTY)? Try another port. Also, if you type the IP address in your browser without typing the port number then the browser will connect to port 80 which is the default port for http. You have a server (either Apache or Nginx or lighttpd) already running on port 80 because you can see the folder structure

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try it as soon as I get home.

Comment: Yeah, trying another port was the solution. I thought if ssh is using 22, i have to use the same in the code. I set it with process.env.port to 3000 and everything is working correctly. Thank you.